# Windows user SYSTEM call another exe

Tags: c#

I currently have a service that watches a folder then passes a file path to a program I wrote which runs as 'SYSTEM' but then the program is suppose to kick off another .exe but for some reason it doesn't call it.

Is there an issue with c# and calling another program from the 'SYSTEM' user?

I am using the system.diagnostics class to accomplish this but the last .exe never gets called.

Has anyone came across this problem before?

I can post code up if it would help?

edit----

```
try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proc = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

                strCmdText = @" -i -a -id:" + station;
                proc.UseShellExecute = false;
                proc.RedirectStandardError = true;
                proc.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                proc.FileName = path + "\\process.exe";
                proc.UserName = "username";
                proc.Arguments = strCmdText;
                dataLog.log(proc.FileName + strCmdText);
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(proc);
            }
            catch(Exception errorProc)
            {
                dataLog.log(errorProc.ToString());
            }
```

It doesn't error out it just says access denied but the folder is set to be read and write for the SYSTEM user and all other users.

Thanks,

Comment: When in doubt, always post code

Comment: Have you tried your same code in a non-service environment? SYSTEM doesn't load a user profile as a service so spawning normal executables isn't supported IIRC.EDIT: I did recall correctly, see this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa480152.aspx#appcomp_topic12 You can't spawn normal Windows executables from a Windows Service.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out it was an exception I didn't catch thanks for the help.